# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object for Sorry! game

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create the board game Sorry! But I cannot seem to find the error. It gives me the error:

"TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object" line 33. I will underline the line it gives the error.

I also need help to insert the "push enter to 'gamble'" function, as I don't know how to insert the keyboard function.

```
import random  #***import random module******import random module******import random module***

participants = int(input("Enter the amount of players: ")) #asks for amount of players

players = []

for i in range(participants): #asks for player's names
    names = input(f"Enter the player's names: {i+1}: ") #player inputs name
    players.append(names) #adds name to player
    
sorry_board = [0] * 50 #board total spaces

dice_uno = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dice_dos = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

def gamble_roll():
    roll_uno = dice_uno[random.randint(0, len(dice_uno)-1)]#len used to retrieve length of list
    roll_dos = dice_dos[random.randint(0, len(dice_dos)-1)]#random function used to generate random number
    return roll_uno + roll_dos

def player_movement (player, gamble):
    sorry_board[player] += gamble
    for i in range(participants):
        if i != participants and sorry_board[i] == sorry_board[player]:
            sorry_board[i] = 0

def board_hud (): #displays board #hud=heads_up_display
    for i in range(participants):
        print(f"{players[i]}: {sorry_board[i]}")              
gambles = [0] * participants
while True:
    for i in range(participants):   
        dice_uno, dice_dos =  gamble_roll()
        if dice_uno == dice_dos:
            gambles[i] += 1
            if gambles[i] == 2:
                sorry_board[i] = 0
                gambles[i] == 0
            else:
                player_movement(i, dice_uno)
        else:
            gambles[i] = 0
            player_movement(i, dice_uno)
        if sorry_board[i] >= 50:
            print(f"{players[i]} wins!")
            
            play_again = input("Would you like to play again? ")
            if play_again.lower() == "yes":
                sorry_board = [0] * 50
                gambles = [0] * participants
            else:
                exit()
            
            board_hud()
```

Comment: dice_uno, dice_dos =  gamble_roll() 
is what is giving me the type errror below the 'while true' statement, line 33

Comment: Instead of highlighting the line, post the full traceback message. We are used to them.

Comment: For debug, place `print("test", gamble_roll())` just before the failing line. You'll see it returns a single integer, not the two things you expect. `print` is your friend!

Comment: dice_uno, dice_dos =  gamble_roll()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Comment: Right. But post the full traceback message in the question. That's the most helpful.

Comment: As an aside, `dice_uno[random.randint(0, len(dice_uno)-1)]` could be `random.choice(dice_uno)`.

Comment: okay understood, im still new to how this site is used.

i ran the test debug, it returned a 14. so does that hint that i mightve used the wrong variables somewhere?

Comment: `gamble_roll` returns the sum of the two dice as a single integer. But then you use it like it is returning the two dice values as a pair. One of these is wrong. You likely want `gamble_roll` to `return roll_uno, roll_dos` - assuming you don't also want to use the sum somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging and especially when posting on Stack Overflow, it's best to write a minimal example of the problem and work with that small bit of experimental code. This has the same problem as your original and it's easier to spot the problem:

```
import random

dice_uno = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dice_dos = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

def gamble_roll():
    roll_uno = dice_uno[random.randint(0, len(dice_uno)-1)]#len used to retrieve length of list
    roll_dos = dice_dos[random.randint(0, len(dice_dos)-1)]#random function used to generate random number
    return roll_uno + roll_dos

dice_uno, dice_dos =  gamble_roll()
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/td/tmp/d/j.py", line 11, in <module>
    dice_uno, dice_dos =  gamble_roll()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

That's easier to work with. The problem is that `gamble_roll` returns the sum of the dice but you are expecting to get the two dice values. Change the return value of `gamble_roll` and it will work.

```
import random

dice_uno = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
dice_dos = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

def gamble_roll():
    roll_uno = dice_uno[random.randint(0, len(dice_uno)-1)]#len used to retrieve length of list
    roll_dos = dice_dos[random.randint(0, len(dice_dos)-1)]#random function used to generate random number
    return roll_uno, roll_dos

dice_uno, dice_dos =  gamble_roll()
```

As a side note, `random.choice` does the same thing as your `randint` code but more concisely. And you don't really need those local variables.

```
def gamble_roll():
    return random.choice(dice_uno), random.choice(dice_duo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to replace this `return roll_uno + roll_dos` with this `return roll_uno, roll_dos`